# Pinging other random public IP gives no result

Tags: networking, ip

I try to ping some random IPs, But most of them fail. I got a dynamic public IP by using Huawei mobile modem. But Whenever I try to ping other public ip I am not getting any result..

I can able to ping 8.8.8.8 or other public web servers, But not getting result for random public ips

Comment: Firewall, currently not assigned, ...

Comment: I can able to ping 8.8.8.8 or other public web servers, But not getting result for random public ips

Comment: My comment was concerned with those IPs, not your setup. I can tell my firewall to block (basically just ignore) pings, for example.

Comment: Just tell can you able to ping My ip. now: 117.219.206.21

Comment: Yes, I can. About 300ms from Germany right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing is that a ping is ICMP Traffic that can be blocked by firewalls. Some admins block such traffic for security reasons.

The other thing is that a host could be offline.